# How to make all child processes of a service follow the same OOM score adjustment

Tags: debian, systemd, out-of-memory

I've installed [BOINC](https://wiki.debian.org/BOINC) on a Debian 11 machine which has plenty of idle CPU but little free memory. Sometimes the OOM killer steps in, and it invariably kills something other than the busy BOINC processes.

I've used [OOMScoreAdjust](https://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#OOMScoreAdjust=) on the BOINC service unit and the other services I want to keep, however the oom_adj score in procfs shows this is not propagated to the child processes, so the real memory-consuming processes spawned by BOINC remain around score 0, as do the processes I want to preserve.

How to propagate the OOM score adjustments I want by using only systemd configuration? Is my only chance to install [earlyoom](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/earlyoom/earlyoom.1.en.html) and configure it so it intervenes on the boinc processes before the oom killer kills the wrong processes?